# Why this function is not returning anything?

Tags: swift

```
func RevisarConectividad() -> String
    {
        var Estado = ""
        let Referencia = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")

        Referencia.observe(.value, with:
        { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false
            {
                Estado = "Conectado"
            }
            else
            {
                Estado = "NoConectado"
            }
            print(Estado)
        })
        print("Estado:" + " " + Estado)
        return Estado


    }
```

I call it like:

```
let Estado = RevisarConectividad()
```

But for some reason, it seems Estado never took any of the both string. Anyway, I print "Estado" inside the closure and it is working, it prints its value correctly.

Comment: It is an asynchrony problem,  this function returns immediately, while the function inside `.observe` is still not called, Firebase and Network connections must be handled using callbacks and completion handlers, not return values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"observe" is a **Async func**, when you return "estado" the value is not set it yet. You can pass a callback, and call it inside your function.

```
func RevisarConectividad(completion: @escaping (_ state:String) -> ())
{
    var Estado = ""
    let Referencia = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")

    Referencia.observe(.value, with:
        { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false
            {
                Estado = "Conectado"
            }
            else
            {
                Estado = "NoConectado"
            }
            completion(Estado)
    })
}
```

and then:

```
RevisarConectividad { (state) in
    print(state)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Database.observe` is asynchronous, you're returning `Estado` with its initial value `""` because the `return Estado` line runs before the actual assignment inside the `observe` closure.

Set breakpoints in `return` and in the assignments to `Estado` and see the execution order.

You need to use some asynchronous pattern: pass a closure to `RevisarConectividad` to be called when you have the data, or a delegate protocol, or KVO of some property...